# Retrieve JObject member from a JArray using SelectToken

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following json parsed into a `JObject`:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(@"{
    ""event"": {
      ""name"": ""daniel""
    },
    ""markets"": [
      {}
    ]
 }");
```

With that `JObject` I'm trying to retrieve the empty `JObject` that's in the `markets` `JArray`.

I'm currently trying `json.SelectToken("$.event.markets[0]")` but that's not working, it returns `null` rather than the empty `JObject` that I expect.

***Is there a way to get that empty `JObject` by using the `SelectToken` || `SelectTokens` method?***  I'd prefer to stay away from using linq, but if I must I must.

Comment: If you where deserialising to a real class a custom deserialiser could have done the work.  in JsonConverter >  ItemConverter , specify a simple converter that return new object if it's null.

Comment: This should be json.SelectToken("$.markets[0]")  instead of json.SelectToken("$.event.markets[0]")  as markets is not contained within the event object.

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend Thank you!  I silly mistake on my part.  Well spotted.  This could be an answer!

Comment: Answer added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be `json.SelectToken("$.markets[0]")` instead of `json.SelectToken("$.event.markets[0]")`  as markets is not contained within the event object.